# IndexError: list index out of range in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run a simple script in python

```
import sys
fname = sys.argv[1]
lname = sys.argv[2]
print 'Hello', fname, lname
```

I am getting this error

**

```
traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
   fname = sys.argv[1]
ndexError: list index out of range
```

**

Any idea.

Thanks

Comment: how do you run this script

Comment: You don't pass any cmdline args.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing arguments to the script

Do like this:

```
python simplescript.py Johnny Melavo
```

Where `simplescript.py` is the name of your python script. It should output:

```
Hello Johnny Melavo
```

Basically `sys.argv` is a list that holds the script path plus the arguments passed to the script. If you don't pass any argument, the length will be only `1`, and therefore the exception while trying to access the position `[1]` or `[2]`  of the list.

Always read carefully the exception messages.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the arguments , the error is coming because it has the array with no values and when you try to fetch values with index 1 and 2 , it gives error.